# How to remove entries in jQuery textboxlist via javascript

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, textboxlist

I'm using jQuery textboxlist, at this moment the devthought.com website is down so I can't access the documentation: is there a way to delete all the entries via javascript? I cant find a method to do this in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try removing it from DOM and create a new one? 
After removing,

```
$('#form_tags_input').textboxlist();
```

I couldn't see a delete method in website. (it works time by time now.)

Comment: Of course some documentation is available via Google Cache:   http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dCqQmtlWvbIJ:devthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist/+jquery+textboxlist&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

Comment: Thanks, it's ugly but it works, thank you for Google Cache link, very useful!